# recursive series in a metric-space

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let's say that you have a series in a metrix space, defined recursively with $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$.
Let's also say that you are given the knowledge that this series converges.

Is it then possible that f is not continous?

(The reason I am asking is that I read two different proofs of Banach's fixed point theorem. In one proof he used that since the contraction f is continious and he knows that the series converges, he gets
$a=lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n+1}= lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n) \text{---continuity-->} = f( lim_{n\to\infty}x_n)  = f(a)$.

But in the other proof, he only says that since he knows that the series converges, he onlys says that we must have $a=f(a)$.)

So this makes me wonder, if we are given info that $x(n+1)= f(x_n)$, converges, without nececarrily knowing that f is continous, are there then examples of functions where f is not continious and this work, or can we deduce from this that $f$ **must** be continous? And you still have that $f(a)=a$?

Comment: In Banach's fixed point theorem, the map is a contraction, and therefore continuous.  One of those writers perhaps didn't point this out explicitly, assuming the reader would observe it himself.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X = [0,1]$ and

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, x = 0\\ \frac{x}{2} &, x \neq 0. \end{cases}$$

For every $x_0 \in X$, the sequence defined by the recursion converges (to $0$), yet $f$ is not continuous and has no fixed point.

The variant

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, x \in X\setminus \mathbb{Q}\\ \frac{x}{2} & x \in X\cap\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

gives an example of a function that has a unique fixed point, such that the sequence obtained by iteratively applying $g$ converges to the fixed point for all starting points, but the function is not continuous in the fixed point (nor in any other point, here). The continuity of the function cannot be deduced from the result that every iterated sequence converges to the unique fixed point, it must be - in one form or other - part of the premises.

In the Banach fixed point theorem, one of the premises is the existence of a $q < 1$ such that for all $x,y$ we have $d(f(x),f(y)) \leqslant q\cdot d(x,y)$. That premise implies the continuity of $f$, and was apparently *implicitly* used in the second proof.

Comment: Thanks. But if we know we have convergence to a, can it be proven that the only possible case that then gives a = f(a) is if f is continous? I see that in your example, you have convergence to 0, but f(0) is not 0, will this happen every time f is not continous?

Comment: To be a little clearer, is this statement true, and can be proven: premise: series = x(n+1) = f(x(n)), and series converges to a, and a=f(a) -----> f is continous in a

Comment: No, that doesn't follow. I'll add a modified example showing that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see now that your first example was actually enough to show that what is done in Banachs theorem you atleast have to have in the back of your mind that f is continous, because else you can't deduce that f(a)=a. But thanks also very much for also proving what I asked for!